# Rewriting URL:s with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo

Please help me. I spent a lot of time trying to do SEO optimization via a URL link in a .htaccess file but I am unable.

`http://www.poplat.com/villa/?option=com_resmania&unit_id=1&isGroup=0&act=Unit&task=details&Itemid=282`

The figure should be optimized for SEO, for example:

`http://www.poplat.com/villa/apartment/dream/`

I tried to do something in the form, but it doesn't work:

```
## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^villa/([^/]+)/([^/]+)ap1-dream /option=com_resmania&unit_id=$1&isGroup=0&act=Unit&task=details&Itemid=$2 [NC]
```

---

I tried this command with no results:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^villa/apartment/dream.html$ villa/?option=com_resmania&unit_id=1&isGroup=0&act=Unit&task=details&Itemid=282
```

My site is a CMS using Joomla 2.5.

Comment: not sure but try [NC,QSA] and change "/option=..." to "/?option=..."

Answer (score 0):

Make .htacess file as given below and place it in root folder of ur website

This will redirect all pages with ?option=...... to villa/apartment/dream.html

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^villa/apartment/dream.html$ villa/?option=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&unit_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&isGroup=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&act=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&task=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&Itemid=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

And this will redirect only that page you written to villa/apartment/dream.html

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^villa/apartment/dream.html$ villa/?option=com_resmania&unit_id=1&isGroup=0&act=Unit&task=details&Itemid=282
```

General Guide

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^villa/apartment/dream(.*).html$ villa/?option=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Take guide from [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Make Sure **mod_rewrite** is turned on in php using  **phpinfo()** function

Comment: I tried the command and it does not happen anything.
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^villa/apartment/dream.html$ villa/?option=com_resmania&unit_id=1&isGroup=0&act=Unit&task=details&Itemid=282

my base of site is CMS joomla 2.5

Comment: Have you checked this 
mod_rewrite is turned on in php using phpinfo() function